# Изменение хранимой строки подключения в C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Встретил схожие вопросы, но в силу неопытности не смог переложить на свою ситуацию. Вводная:

- Есть несколько контуров подключения для приложения (например, тестовый, боевой сервер, еще какой-нибудь тестовый).
- Строки подключения для каждой базы храню в app.config (да, это не безопасно, но доступ к приложению только у проверенных пользователей, сейчас главное - чтобы работало уж как-нибудь).
- Добавил на форму DataGridView
- Сразу в источнике указал БД SQL Server
- Сразу создавая DataSet, где источником указал БД, для которой тут же указал ConnectionString, которая теперь хранится в программе.

Но что, если мне нужно будет изменить строку подключения? Предположим, я считал в переменную newConnString строку подключения из app.config. Как мне теперь заменить её в источнике данных?

Comment: Если у вас есть несколько окружений, куда вы деплоите ваше приложение, и на этих окружениях должны быть разные кофиги - то для этого лучше всего использовать конфиг-трансформации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько это разумно, но это работает. Сперва открыл файл Settings.Designer.cs Можно найти в Solution Explorer, открыв вложения:

> Properties->Settings.settings->Settings.Designer->Settings

Нашел там свою строку подключения. По умолчанию у неё есть только get{}. Соответственно, добавил:

```
    public string My_ConnectionString {
        get 
        {
            return ((string)(this["My_ConnectionString"]));
        }
        set
        {
            this["My_ConnectionString"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Теперь можно обращаться к ней:

```
  ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.My_ConnectionString= "blah-blah-blah";
```

И уже в рантайме беру строку из конфигов и на лету вставляю сюда.

Comment: Недостаток этого способа в том, что при автоматической правке файла (например, если добавил еще строку подключения). То все изменения слетают и надо писать сеты заново.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете изменить строку подключения в адаптере.

```
TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString=newConnectionString;
```